# R: Convert several columns from [1,2] to Boolean [TRUE,FALSE]

Tags: r, boolean, multiple-columns

I have a data frame (imported with read.csv) which has many, but not all, columns which have boolean data which is encoded as 1=false, 2= true.

I would like to convert all of them to booleans. I know I can do

```
data$someCol <- data$someCol == 2
```

My questions:

- Is this the best way?
- Is there another in which I can specify BOTH "1" for FALSE and "2" for TRUE, with NA for the rest?
- Can I somehow "mass-process" columns like this, selecting via grep?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show few lines of example data and expected output?.  So, if all the columns are not encoded as 1 or 2, what do you want with those columns?

Comment: I want to do the conversion only for selected columns (based on name). All other columns must remain the way they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may convert the elements that are not 1 or 2 to `NA` and just use the logical condition `df1==2` to transform it to a logical matrix with `TRUE` as 2, `FALSE` as 1, and the rest `NA`

```
 is.na(df1) <- !(df1==1|df1==2)
 df1==2
```

For large dataset, it may be better to use `lapply` to loop through the columns

```
 df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) {x[!x %in% c(1,2)] <- NA
                          x==2})
```

#### Update

If we want to apply only a subset of columns with column names that start with 'XX', `grep` would be option to subset the columns and then loop with `lapply` on that subset of columns and replace that columns with the output of `lapply`.

```
 indx <- grep('^XX', colnames(df2))
 df2[indx] <- lapply(df2[indx], function(x) {x[!x %in% c(1,2)] <- NA
                          x==2})
```

---

Another option would be using `mutate_each` from `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 mutate_each(df2, funs((NA^!. %in% 1:2)*.==2), matches('^XX'))
```

We select the columns that have names that start with XX (`matches('^XX')`), create the logical condition within the `funs`.  The `.` means any element within in a column.

```
 . %in% 1:2
```

gives a logical output.  If the element is 1 or 2, we get `TRUE` and if not `FALSE`.

```
   (NA^!. %in% 1:2)
```

We negate (`!`)  the output of `TRUE/FALSE` so that TRUE becomes FALSE and FALSE changes to TRUE, change the TRUE values to NA (`NA^!...`), thus converting values that are not 1 or 2 to NA and all other values to 1.

```
  *.==2
```

Then we multiply `*` the values we got from the earlier output so that the NA value remain as NA and 1 value get changed to the value in that position, for e.g. `1*2=2`.  This can be made into a logical output by `.==2`.  If the values are 2, will return as TRUE or else (i.e. 1) return FALSE.

Using `mutate_each` will not change the original object unless we assign to the original object name

```
  df2 <- mutate_each(df2, funs((NA^!. %in% 1:2)*.==2), matches('^XX'))
```

Another option without the need to assign it back would be using `%<>%` operator from `magrittr`

```
  library(magrittr)
  df2 %<>%
        mutate_each(funs((NA^!. %in% 1:2)*.==2), matches('^XX'))
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5, 20*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
 df2 <- df1
 colnames(df2)[c(2,4)] <- paste0('XX', 1:2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This takes care of the NA problem. Can I restrict the "lapply" to just SOME columns in df? I.e. only columns whose name starts with "XX" (which may be many, but not all in the frame)?

Comment: Thanks, perfect! I used the first option which seems clearest to me.